# Extending Enumeration

Tags: scala

I've implemented a method `withNameOption` that returns `None` if the enumeration member with specific name is not found but I have trouble extracting it to a trait to use it for all the enumerations in the app. At the moment code looks like this:

```
object FileType extends Enumeration with EnumUtils {
  type FileType = Value

  def withNameOption(name: String): Option[FileType] = try {
    Some(withName(name))
  } catch {
    case _: NoSuchElementException => None
  }
  val scala, java, ruby = Value
}
```

Using `this.type` wherever possible doesn't typecheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the pattern you're looking for:

```
trait EnumUtils {
  thisenum: Enumeration =>

  def withNameOption(name: String): Option[thisenum.type#Value] = try {
    Some(thisenum.withName(name))
  } catch {
    case _: NoSuchElementException => None
  }
}

object FileType extends Enumeration with EnumUtils {
  type FileType = Value

  val scala, java, ruby = Value
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Python: " + FileType.withNameOption("python"))
    println("Scala: " + FileType.withNameOption("scala"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Where can I read about the `thisenum: Enumeration =>`line cause at the moment it all looks like magic?

Comment: This seems to be the best thing I could find quickly: http://marcus-christie.blogspot.com/2014/03/scala-understanding-self-type.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the specific error you're seeing?

You might prefer to use the "pimp my library pattern" to add this method onto existing Enumerations, rather than using a trait.